# Solution to Magento Always Populate Data Error, php.ini file not working?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2.1.5 and I'm currently stuck on the readiness check. It is currently giving this error

> PHP Settings Check * Need Help? PHP Documentation Your PHP Version is
>   5.6.30, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This
>   will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file
>   and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help
>   please call your hosting provider.

I have renamed the php.ini file and have included the stipulated line and still have no luck. My ini file is as follows:

```
; Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
; See COPYING.txt for license details.
; This file is for CGI/FastCGI installations.
; Try copying it to php5.ini, if it doesn't work

memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 18000

; disable automatic session start
; before autoload was initialized

flag session.auto_start = off
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
; enable resulting html compression

zlib.output_compression = on

; disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

suhosin.session.cryptua = off

; PHP for some reason ignores this setting in system php.ini
; and disables mcrypt if this line is missing in local php.ini

extension=mcrypt.so

; Disable PHP errors, notices and warnings output in production mode to prevent exposing sensitive information.

display_errors = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure this line is in your PHP.ini file. Edit your PHP.ini file and add it in:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

To check it has worked, run PHP on the command line and search for the setting:

```
php -i | grep always_populate_raw_post_data
```

You should find the setting now appears as -1:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data => -1
```

You should now be able to get past this error message.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just seen the necessary line lurking in your .ini file, however it looks like you're missing a semicolon (';') or new line after:

```
flag session.auto_start = off
```

In fact the whole block looks wrong! The 'flag' keyword looks out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file and find always_populate_raw_post_data, set it to always_populate_raw_post_data = -1.
Save php.ini & 
Restart your web server.